# Can an Altair facet chart have alternating background colors?

Tags: python, altair

Is it possible to set alternate background colors in a facet chart? The following attempt to set fill equal to a nominal column results in all black backgrounds.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data = {'source': ['a','a','a','a','a','b','b','b','b','b','c','c','c','c','c']
                   ,'x':[5,4,3,2,1,5,4,3,2,1,5,4,3,2,1]
                   ,'y':[1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5]
                   ,'fill':['yes','yes','yes','yes','yes','no','no','no','no','no','yes','yes','yes','yes','yes']})

print(df)

   source  x  y fill
0       a  5  1  yes
1       a  4  2  yes
2       a  3  3  yes
3       a  2  4  yes
4       a  1  5  yes
5       b  5  1   no
6       b  4  2   no
7       b  3  3   no
8       b  2  4   no
9       b  1  5   no
10      c  5  1  yes
11      c  4  2  yes
12      c  3  3  yes
13      c  2  4  yes
14      c  1  5  yes

alt.Chart(df).mark_line().encode(x='x:Q',y='y:Q'
        ).properties(height=100,width=200
        ).facet(column='source').configure_view(fill='fill:N')
```

Result:
[image: black background]

Desired result is an alternating background color like this:
[image: alternating background]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is currently no way to do this within a facet chart in Altair (Vega-Lite provides no encoding for facet background; when you write `fill='fill:N'` the renderer interprets `fill:N` as the name of a non-existent HTML color).

If you want alternating backgrounds, the only way to do this currently is to manually concatenate charts with different backgrounds.

Answer (score 2):

For manually concatenating the chart, I don't think it is possible to concatenate charts with either a background or configure object. A workaround could be to create a rectangle mark manually in the background layer:

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

source = data.cars()
chart = alt.Chart(source).mark_circle().encode(
    x='Horsepower',
    y='Miles_per_Gallon',
)

bg = chart.mark_rect(color='coral').encode(
    x=alt.value(0),
    y=alt.value(0),
    x2=alt.value(400),
    y2=alt.value(300))

(bg + chart) | (bg.mark_rect(color='gold') + chart)
```

[image]